# Console output to String

Tags: vb.net, string, stream

I'm working on a little app that requires the results of a dsquery and dsget set in a string for clean up (replacing spaces and other not needed characters).  I can display the results of the stream with ReadToEnd - but can't seem to find anything on getting it into a string.

VB.net - visual basic 2010

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim p As New Process
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "program"
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "lots here"
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    p.Start()
    Dim reader As StreamReader = p.StandardOutput
    p.WaitForExit()
    MsgBox(reader.ReadToEnd)
End Sub
```

Comment: just add parentheses at the end of `reader.ReadToEnd`.

Answer (score 1):

just write

```
dim ProcOutput as string 
ProcOutput = reader.ReadToEnd()
```

instead of the last line.

if that doesn't help, then I suggest you check out this article:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/launchprocess.aspx